# JSON deserialization of children

Tags: vb.net, json, deserialization

I have this json output:

```
{
"status": "SUCCESS",
"candidates": [
    {
        "race": "KENYA",
        "candidates": [
            {
                "picture": “http: //api.iebc.or.ke/images/candidate/5FFCD75B-A067-E211-8158-00505687000D.jpg”
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

I can read status when i deserialize it. However, I need to read the inner values, too, ie, race, candidates, picture values.

```
    Dim myWebClient As New Net.WebClient()
    Dim responseArray As Byte() = myWebClient.DownloadData(iebcsite)
    json = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responseArray)
    Dim deserializedProduct As Object = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Object)(json)

    Response.Write(deserializedProduct)

    obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json)
    Uptime = obj.Item("status").ToString
```

Can someone show me how to read the value of child picture?

thanks.

Comment: @biziclop - Why, that's not c#...